# Borel sets and Lebesgue-Stieltjes measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $F : \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a distribution function (increasing right continuous), and $m_F : M_F\to[0,\infty]$ the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure generated by $F$.

In most cases I've come across there are sets in $M_F$ that are not Borel sets.

> Is the general statement "For every choice of $F$, $M_F$ contains a set which isn't a Borel set" a theorem?

Comment: what is your definition of $ M_F $ ?

Comment: @Joey Doey : $m_F : M_F→[0,∞]$ is the Caratheodory extension of $m : S→[0,∞]$ with S collection of semi-open intervals (a,b] and m defined by m(a,b] = F(b) - F(a).